# Is it possible to use my Firebase Function, for iOS notifications?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I already have this cloud function for my android app uploaded to Firebase Functions.

```
exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/Notifications/{user_id}/{notification_id}').onWrite((change, context) => {

  const user_id = context.params.user_id;
  const notification_id = context.params.notification_id;

  //Get name
  const fromUser = admin.database().ref(`/Notifications/${user_id}/${notification_id}`).once('value');
    return fromUser.then(fromUserResult => {
                var from_user_id = fromUserResult.val().from;

                if(from_user_id === null){
                     from_user_id = "BeBetter"
                }

                console.log('You have a new notification from :' + from_user_id);

    const userQuery = admin.database().ref(`/Users/${from_user_id}/name`).once('value');

            return userQuery.then(userResult => {

                const userName = userResult.val();
                const afterData = change.after.val();

            //New Type of Notification.
            if (afterData.type === "friend request") {
                const userToken = admin.database().ref('Users/' + user_id + '/user_token').once('value');
                return userToken.then(result => {

                    const token_id = result.val();

                    const payload = {
                        notification: {
                            title: "Friend Request",
                            body: `${userName} sent you a Friend Request! <3`,
                            icon: "default",
                            click_action : "BeBetter_TARGET_NOTIFICATION"
                        },
            data : {
            from_user_id : from_user_id 
            }
                    };

                    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id,payload).then(response => {
                        return console.log('This was the notification feature for friend request');
                        });

                });

            //New Type of Notification.
            } else if(afterData.type === "friend request accepted") {
            const userToken = admin.database().ref('/Users/' + user_id + '/user_token').once('value');
            return userToken.then(result => {

                const token_id = result.val();

                const payload = {
                    notification: {
                        title: "Friend Request Accepted",
                        body: `You've got a new friend! ${userName} <3`,
                        icon: "default",
                        click_action : "BeBetter_TARGET_NOTIFICATION"
                    },
                };

                return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id,payload).then(response => {
                return console.log('This was the notification feature for friend request accept');
                });

            });

        //New Type of Notification.
        } else if(afterData.type === "experience invite") {
            const userToken = admin.database().ref('/Users/' + user_id + '/user_token').once('value');
            return userToken.then(result => {

                const token_id = result.val();

                const payload = {
                    notification: {
                        title: "Experience Invite!",
                        body: `${userName} invited you to an experience!`,
                        icon: "default",
                        click_action : "BeBetter_TARGET_NOTIFICATION"
                    },
                };

                return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id,payload).then(response => {
                return console.log('This was the notification feature for experience invite');
                });

            });


        }else if(afterData.type === "experience completed") {
            const userToken = admin.database().ref('/Users/' + user_id + '/user_token').once('value');
            return userToken.then(result => {

                const token_id = result.val();

                const payload = {
                    notification: {
                        title: "Experience Completed!",
                        body: `${userName} joined! <3`,
                        icon: "default",
                        click_action : "BeBetter_TARGET_NOTIFICATION"
                    },
                };

                return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id,payload).then(response => {
                return console.log('This was the notification feature for experience completed');
                });

            });
        } else {
            console.log('Not a friend request');
            return null;
        }

        });

    });


});
```

Is it possible to use the same function for my iOS app? And how? I've yet, to find a great guide.
My AppDelegate, is super standard. I've set it up for being able to send cloud messages. But want it, to automatically send a notification whenever I write to the notification section of my database.
Best regards

Answer (score 2):

Cloud Functions work for all apps added to a project.  In your case, you have a realtime database onWrite function, which will trigger no matter what code or app writes the database at the pattern you specified.

I strongly suggest you just try it and see if it works.  You don't need to post to Stack Overflow to get authorization to try new things.  Stack Overflow is useful when things don't work the way you expect.  Your question can then share the details.